# laravel で breeze をインストールするとPermission denied

Tags: php, ubuntu, laravel

Windows 10 Pro 22H2 にDocker、Ubuntuを入れてlaravel をインストールできました。
前回は自己解決したのですが、brezze のインストールでまた躓いております。
`artisan breeze:install`
上記コマンドの結果、下記のエラーが発生しました

```
  Which stack would you like to install?
  blade ...................................................................................... 0  
  react ...................................................................................... 1  
  vue ........................................................................................ 2  
  api ........................................................................................ 3  
❯ 0

  Would you like to install dark mode support? (yes/no) [no]
❯ no

  Would you prefer Pest tests instead of PHPUnit? (yes/no) [no]
❯ no


   ErrorException 

  mkdir(): Permission denied

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php:651
    647▕         if ($force) {
    648▕             return @mkdir($path, $mode, $recursive);
    649▕         }
    650▕ 
  ➜ 651▕         return mkdir($path, $mode, $recursive);
    652▕     }
    653▕ 
    654▕     /**
    655▕      * Move a directory.

      +18 vendor frames 

  19  artisan:35
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle()
```

察するに書き込み権限がないのだと思いますが、どこのフォルダかファイルのことを指しているのかがわからないです。
ご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら、ご教示願います。
・php 8.1.2
・Laravel Framework 10.13.5
・Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
・Client: Docker Engine - Community
Cloud integration: v1.0.33
Version:           24.0.2
・Server: Docker Desktop
Engine:
Version:          24.0.2
API version:      1.43 (minimum version 1.12)

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

結局、ローカル環境なので下記のコマンドで全部に権限を付けたらインストールできました。
`chmod -R 777 ./`
すっきりしませんが、先に進みました。